How to debug error {"code":-32603} on solana

I learned solana via soldev.app and I tried to pull source code from: https://github.com/Unboxed-Software/solana-movie-program.git (branch: solution-add-comments) and deploy to testnet.

After deploying, I called smartcontract from react app (https://github.com/Unboxed-Software/solana-movie-frontend.git) and I got the error {"code":-32603}.
How to debug where error come from ?

could you share the full error logs. Also, when testing the smart contract, are you facing a similar error.

Unfortunately that code just means "internal error", which doesn't give too much more info.
Here's the source code for the JSON RPC crate used by Solana's RPC server: https://github.com/apoelstra/rust-jsonrpc/blob/be0758755ca216f9c169ccb747537da97cf4726e/src/error.rs#L160
You'll need to look at any other error info that's provided.

3000 are Account errors in Anchor.
Reference this repo - https://github.com/0xdeepmehta/fuck-anchor/blob/master/src/errors.rs
